# Detect a successful share with the new Facebook Share button

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I am using the [new Share button](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/11/06/introducing-new-like-and-share-buttons/) on Facebook. Is there a way to detect a **share** event? I had a look at the [FB.Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) API but I couldn't find which event matches a successful share.

I used the [`Share Button` documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) to generate the code I'm using.

**JS:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

Comment: do you have any reason why you must use the share button instead of the share dialog?

Comment: I can do it using the `FB.ui` method, but in the new share button method, I get the count together with the share button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the share button doesn't provide the possibility to track the share event, at least as far as I know. 
If you want to "listen" to share events, you want to do what Fabio suggest and use the share dialog: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP_ID&display=popup&link=http://example.com&redirect_uri=http://example.com/someone_shared_on-fb.php`, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with FQL : Facebook query language.

SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count
FROM link_stat
WHERE url="http://www.mysite.com/some-page"

Check your reponse from this link
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

SO everything a user share and u want a track just hold its url and run a query there will provide count of likes,share and comments as well

Cheers and keep rolling

Comment: How will I know if a specific user shared the link?

Comment: If u are using facebook graph api sharer.php call then in that we pass a url so whenever any user share through that u have the url with you . JUst copy the url and apply in above mentioned query and run in FQL.

Comment: does this still works ? is this is good way to do this or just a hack ?